# Chocolatey can't install apps, 'How do you want to open this file?' dialog box is opened instead

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

The dialog opens when I run any `choco install*` command, manually browsing to `choco.exe` in `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey` didn't solve the issue:

[image]

PowerShell version:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14393  0
```

I [installed Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install) by running `iwr https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 -UseBasicParsing | iex`:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        24.8.2016     11.09                chocInstall
Getting latest version of the Chocolatey package for download.
Downloading https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/package/chocolatey/0.10.0 to C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocInstall\chocolatey.zip
Download 7Zip commandline tool
Downloading https://chocolatey.org/7za.exe to C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocInstall\7za.exe
Extracting C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocInstall\chocolatey.zip to C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocInstall...

7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18

Processing archive: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocInstall\chocolatey.zip

Extracting  _rels\.rels
Extracting  chocolatey.nuspec
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateysetup.psm1
Extracting  tools\init.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\choco.exe
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\choco.exe.ignore
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\LICENSE.txt
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\chocolateyInstaller.psm1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\chocolateyProfile.psm1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\chocolateyScriptRunner.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\ChocolateyTabExpansion.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Format-FileSize.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Get-CheckSumValid.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Get-ChocolateyUnzip.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Get-ChocolateyWebFile.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Get-EnvironmentVariable.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Get-EnvironmentVariableNames.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Get-FtpFile.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Get-OSArchitectureWidth.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Get-ToolsLocation.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Get-UACEnabled.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Get-UninstallRegistryKey.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Get-VirusCheckValid.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Get-WebFile.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Get-WebFileName.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Get-WebHeaders.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Install-BinFile.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Install-ChocolateyDesktopLink.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Install-ChocolateyEnvironmentVariable.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Install-ChocolateyExplorerMenuItem.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Install-ChocolateyFileAssociation.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Install-ChocolateyPackage.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Install-ChocolateyPath.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Install-ChocolateyPinnedTaskBarItem.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Install-ChocolateyPowershellCommand.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Install-ChocolateyShortcut.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Install-ChocolateyVsixPackage.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Install-ChocolateyZipPackage.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Install-Vsix.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Set-EnvironmentVariable.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Set-PowerShellExitCode.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Start-ChocolateyProcessAsAdmin.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Test-ProcessAdminRights.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Uninstall-BinFile.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Uninstall-ChocolateyEnvironmentVariable.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Uninstall-ChocolateyPackage.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\UnInstall-ChocolateyZipPackage.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Update-SessionEnvironment.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Write-ChocolateyFailure.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Write-ChocolateySuccess.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\functions\Write-FileUpdateLog.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\redirects\choco.exe
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\redirects\choco.exe.ignore
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\redirects\chocolatey.exe
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\redirects\chocolatey.exe.ignore
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\redirects\cinst.exe
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\redirects\cinst.exe.ignore
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\redirects\clist.exe
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\redirects\clist.exe.ignore
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\redirects\cpack.exe
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\redirects\cpack.exe.ignore
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\redirects\cpush.exe
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\redirects\cpush.exe.ignore
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\redirects\cuninst.exe
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\redirects\cuninst.exe.ignore
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\redirects\cup.exe
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\redirects\cup.exe.ignore
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\redirects\cver.exe
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\redirects\cver.exe.ignore
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\redirects\RefreshEnv.cmd
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\tools\7z.dll
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\tools\7z.exe
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\tools\7z.exe.ignore
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\tools\7z.exe.manifest
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\tools\7zip.license.txt
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\tools\checksum.exe
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\tools\checksum.exe.config
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\tools\checksum.exe.ignore
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\tools\checksum.license.txt
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\tools\detector.zip
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\tools\shimgen.exe
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\tools\shimgen.exe.ignore
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\tools\shimgen.license.txt
Extracting  package\services\metadata\core-properties\b71b0b2f574b4729aa2134477128b378.psmdcp
Extracting  [Content_Types].xml

Everything is Ok

Files: 87
Size:       11599385
Compressed: 6894450
Installing chocolatey on this machine
Creating ChocolateyInstall as an environment variable (targeting 'Machine')
  Setting ChocolateyInstall to 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey'
WARNING: It's very likely you will need to close and reopen your shell
  before you can use choco.
Restricting write permissions to Administrators
We are setting up the Chocolatey package repository.
The packages themselves go to 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib'
  (i.e. C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\yourPackageName).
A shim file for the command line goes to 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin'
  and points to an executable in 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\yourPackageName'.

Creating Chocolatey folders if they do not already exist.

WARNING: You can safely ignore errors related to missing log files when
  upgrading from a version of Chocolatey less than 0.9.9.
  'Batch file could not be found' is also safe to ignore.
  'The system cannot find the file specified' - also safe.
chocolatey.nupkg file not installed in lib.
 Attempting to locate it from bootstrapper.
Chocolatey (choco.exe) is now ready.
You can call choco from anywhere, command line or powershell by typing choco.
Run choco /? for a list of functions.
You may need to shut down and restart powershell and/or consoles
 first prior to using choco.
Ensuring chocolatey commands are on the path
Ensuring chocolatey.nupkg is in the lib folder
```

I have restarted PowerShell and run as administrator. `Set-ExecutionPolicy` is `Restricted`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type `where.exe choco` to determine where PowerShell believes it is using Chocolatey from.

If there are any other files that come up besides the proper location, such as `C:\Windows\System32\choco`, inspect that file to see what it is and make sure it isn't anything bad. Then remove the improper files.

We have not seen much of this at all (this is maybe the second instance so far), so it is hard to say what may have caused this, whether some small issue during the install or something that was done in your environment prior to or after the install. It is something we are keeping an eye on.

Comment: Command output: `C:\Windows\System32\choco
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\choco.exe`

Comment: Remove the file in system32 - but also, determine the contents of the file. It's not something that choco has created.

Comment: It was an empty file (`0 bytes`), I have no idea how it has been created. My issue is now resolved, please edit your question

Comment: Is it normal that PowerShell is pointing to `C:\WINDOWS\system32>`? That's the default path when opening.

Comment: Yes, that is normal when opened as an administrator.

Comment: I had the same exact issue, same exact symptoms, same fix resolved it. No idea where the C:\Windows\System32\choco 0b file came from, though. Thanks!

Comment: Same issue here, then found the 0b choco under System32 and deleting it fixed the issue